# Evaluate Time Dependent Rate of Return to create Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, optimization

Suppose that I have a Pandas dataframe as follows:

```
+------------+--------+
|    Date    | Price  |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-07-30 | 438.51 |
| 2021-08-02 | 437.59 |
| 2021-08-03 | 441.15 |
| 2021-08-04 | 438.98 |
+------------+--------+
```

The above data frame can be genreated using the code below:

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-07-30', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04'],
        'Price': [438.51, 437.59, 441.15, 438.98]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
normalisation_days = 365.25
compounding_days = 365.25
```

For the given timeseries I want to compute the `rate_of_return` which is time dependent and problem here is to identify the time periods between which the best or worst values of `rate_of_return` is achieved.

One could simply calculate `rate_of_return` on all possible combinations and then create a data frame containing `period_start` `period_end` and `rate_of_return` and sort in descending (best) or ascending (worst) order and then exclude any periods where there is overlap.

`rate_of_return = ((period_end_price/period_start_price)^(compounding_days/(days_in_between))-1 * (normalisation_days/compounding_days)`

On above data frame I've computed `rate_of_return` using code below

```
df['rate_of_return_l1'] = ((((df.Price /
                                   df.Price[0]) **
                                  (compounding_days /
                                   (df.Date - df.Date[0]).dt.days) - 1) *
                                 (normalisation_days /
                                  compounding_days)))
df['rate_of_return_l1'].iloc[0] = np.nan

df['rate_of_return_l2'] = ((((df.Price /
                                   df.Price[1]) **
                                  (compounding_days /
                                   (df.Date - df.Date[1]).dt.days) - 1) *
                                 (normalisation_days /
                                  compounding_days)))
df['rate_of_return_l2'].iloc[:2] = np.nan

df['rate_of_return_l3'] = ((((df.Price /
                                   df.Price[2]) **
                                  (compounding_days /
                                   (df.Date - df.Date[2]).dt.days) - 1) *
                                 (normalisation_days /
                                  compounding_days)))
df['rate_of_return_l3'].iloc[:3] = np.nan
```

Based on the results the best/worst cases period are as below

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Period Start | Period End | Rate of Return |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2021-08-02   | 2021-08-03 |    18.28751739 |
| 2021-08-02   | 2021-08-04 |    0.784586925 |
| 2021-07-30   | 2021-08-03 |    0.729942907 |
| 2021-07-30   | 2021-08-04 |    0.081397181 |
| 2021-07-30   | 2021-08-02 |   -0.225626914 |
| 2021-08-03   | 2021-08-04 |   -0.834880227 |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

**Expected Output**

If I want to see the best of `rate_of_return` the resulting dataframe would be

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Period Start | Period End | Rate of Return |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2021-08-02   | 2021-08-03 |    18.28751739 |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

If I want to see the worst of `rate_of_return` the resulting dataframe would be

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Period Start | Period End | Rate of Return |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2021-08-03   | 2021-08-04 |   -0.834880227 |
| 2021-07-30   | 2021-08-02 |   -0.225626914 |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

- What we be the optimal approach to test out all scenarios to compute `rate_of_return`?
- How can I achieve the expected output such that periods don't overlap? (seen in expected output)
- Best/Worst data frame is not sign dependent best data frame can contain negative `rate_of_returns` given that there is no time period overlap.
- What would the approach be if formula changes to `(period_end_price/period_start_price) - 1`(not time dependent)?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimal" here? What is sub-optimal about the approach you are taking?

Comment: The code that I've shared creates a separate column for each start date. If the time frame increases say if there are 500 data points I would have to create 499 columns to evaluate the `rate_of_return`. Also the expected output requires non-overlapping time periods so there can be an optimal approach to do such calculation. How can I get best/worst performance such that there is no overlap in periods as seen in expected output?

Comment: Also the shared code leads to intermediary dataframe and not the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, there are two parts to your question -

### Part 1: Generating combinations

For generating combinations, you can use `itertools`, compute the returns for each combination and sort the results.

```py
from itertools import combinations
rors = []
for combination in combinations(zip(df['Date'], df['Price']), 2):
    (start_date, start_price), (end_date, end_price) = combination
    ror = (end_price / start_price) ** (compounding_days / (end_date - start_date).days) - 1
    rors.append((start_date, end_date, ror))

sorted_rors = sorted(rors, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
print(sorted_rors[0])
#(Timestamp('2021-08-02 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2021-08-03 00:00:00'),
# 18.28751738702541)

print(sorted_rors[-1])
#(Timestamp('2021-08-03 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2021-08-04 00:00:00'),
# -0.8348802270491325)
```

### Part 2: Non Overlapping Time Periods

This part I am not very clear about, but I am guessing you are trying to find the ***top n*** returns with time periods that do not overlap. If the number of time periods you are looking at is large, you can think of using a generator function -

```py
def next_non_overlapping(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    first_start, first_end, first_ror = next(it)
    yield (first_start, first_end, first_ror)
    while True:
        try:
            next_start, next_end, next_ror = next(it)
            if next_start >= first_end or next_end <= first_start:
                yield (next_start, next_end, next_ror)
                first_start, first_end, first_ror = next_start, next_end, next_ror
        except StopIteration:
            print("No more items")
            break

nno = next_non_overlapping(sorted_rors)
print(next(nno))
#(Timestamp('2021-08-02 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2021-08-03 00:00:00'),
# 18.28751738702541)
print(next(nno))
#(Timestamp('2021-07-30 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2021-08-02 00:00:00'),
# -0.22562691374181088)
print(next(nno))
#(Timestamp('2021-08-03 00:00:00'),
# Timestamp('2021-08-04 00:00:00'),
# -0.8348802270491325)
print(next(nno))
# No more items
```

For getting the ***n lowest returns***, you can simply pass in the reversed list to the function - i.e.

```py
nnor = next_non_overlapping(reversed(sorted_rors))
```

Comment: To avoid overlap equals sign must be removed if I understand correctly?
`next_start >= first_end or next_end <= first_start`

Comment: Yes, depending on how you define overlap. I considered [1-Jan-2022, 2-Jan-2022] and [2-Jan-2022, 3-Jan-2022] as non overlapping periods for example.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the problem is easier if the time series is daily. So I'd do:

```
df.set_index('Date').resample('d').mean().reset_index()
```

This gets us to:

|  | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-30 00:00:00 | 438.51 |
| 1 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 | nan |
| 2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | nan |
| 3 | 2021-08-02 00:00:00 | 437.59 |
| 4 | 2021-08-03 00:00:00 | 441.15 |
| 5 | 2021-08-04 00:00:00 | 438.98 |

From here you can calculate the rate of return to x-days in the future as:

```
for holding_duration in range(1, 5):
    df[holding_duration] = df['Price'].pct_change(holding_duration).add(1).pow(365.25/holding_duration)
```

This gives:

|  | Date | Price | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-07-30 00:00:00 | 438.51 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | 2021-08-01 00:00:00 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | 2021-08-02 00:00:00 | 437.59 | 0.464356 | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | 2021-08-03 00:00:00 | 441.15 | 19.2875 | 2.9927 | nan | nan |
| 5 | 2021-08-04 00:00:00 | 438.98 | 0.16512 | 1.78459 | 1.13931 | nan |

Which could potentially get quite large...

From there you can do a row-wise argmax and derive the holding periods from that.

Not a full solution, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score -3):

Define your function, you can pass directly the data frame and the start, end date:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Date': ['2021-07-30', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04'],
        'Price': [438.51, 437.59, 441.15, 438.98]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
normalisation_days = 365.25
compounding_days = 365.25

def rate_ret(df, start_date, end_date):

    start = df[df.Date==start_date].iloc[0]
    end = df[df.Date==end_date].iloc[0]
    period_start_price = start.Price
    period_end_price = end.Price
    days_in_between = (end.Date - start.Date).days
    return ((period_end_price/period_start_price)**(compounding_days/days_in_between)-1) * (normalisation_days/compounding_days)

# Iterate over all possible date intervals creating an array (or matrix),
#in the second `for` loop, we only include dates bigger than the starting date:

array = []
for start_date in df.Date:
    for end_date in df.Date[df.Date>start_date]:
        array.append([rate_ret(df, start_date, end_date), start_date, end_date])
print(array)

# To extract the best and the worst periods with no overlapping, 
# take the best save it and iteratively save the next comparing if they collide or not with the previous stored intervals:

def extract_non_overlaping(df):
    saved_rows = [df.iloc[0]]
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        for saved in saved_rows:
            if (row['Period End'] < saved['Period Start']) or (row['Period Start'] > saved['Period End']):
                saved_rows.append(row)
                break # avoid saving duplicates
    return pd.DataFrame(saved_rows, columns=['Rate of Return','Period Start','Period End'])

df_higher  = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['Rate of Return','Period Start','Period End']).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['Rate of Return'],ascending=False)
df_lower  = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=['Rate of Return','Period Start','Period End']).reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['Rate of Return'])

extract_non_overlaping(df_higher)
extract_non_overlaping(df_lower)
```

And the result lower:

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Period Start | Period End | Rate of Return |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2021-08-02   | 2021-08-03 |    18.28751739 |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

Higher:

```
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| Period Start | Period End | Rate of Return |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
| 2021-08-03   | 2021-08-04 |   -0.834880227 |
| 2021-07-30   | 2021-08-02 |   -0.225626914 |
+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

If the formula doesn't depend on the time just change the formula in the definition of rete_ret nothing else.

pd: There are some optimizations that you can do, but overall the code works.

Comment: Please read the question carefully the answer completely disregards the expected output and does not takes into account overlapping periods.

Comment: @Lopez now you have the additional piece you wanted working.

Comment: Like stated in question I am looking for an optimal solution. This solution takes a lot of time due to loop when executed on a larger data frame.

Comment: @lopez, you could be just a bit more friendly, so you motivate people to solve your stuff, or to keep improving on their given solution, not the opposite. Specially when it looks you even didn't try to solve your own problem, good luck in any case.